# Could not find an installed version of Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Getting this Error After Update IONIC cli Version,

> (node:11840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not
>   find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on
>   your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle in
>   your path.

Comment: Do you use linux or windows?

Comment: I am using windows.